# Windows Phone 8 Application crash once its launched AgHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

My application crashes once its opened with no exception 
It was working fine but suddenly I got this problem.
On the output console im getting the below:

```
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[296] AgHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403 (0xe0464645).
```

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: It is nasty.  We can't reverse-engineer your program from that exception code, you must post a minimum repro.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you any idea what mscorlib.ni.dll does? Or what "Just my code" is? Or what the -532265403 exit code means? Or what AgHost.exe is?

Comment: Clearly this question is of no use to you.  Click the Ask Question button and document your problem better than this guy did.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  I went to properties for the project, then Application, and made sure the "Startup object" was selected.  After I selected a startup object, everything works fine.

This worked for me. Taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4b96dad-d1bf-475e-b4c3-ab792576bc06/cannot-run-a-wp81-app-in-a-debug-mode-failed-to-run-aghostexe?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 0):

try resetting App.xaml to:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Also try :

Comment: This did not work, i had those things set up like that from the very beginning.