# Upgrading wp8 to wp8.1 silverlight, debugger cannot be launched

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have now had an error with VS2013 and WP8.1 silverlight for a couple of days.

I get a couple of different errors, `..Ensure unlocked screen..`, `AgHost.exe could not be launched`, `port is in use by another program` and `ensure the device is unlocked`.

These errors came suddenly after I retarged the solution. I have no compiling errors. 
**Solution Attempts**

1. Restart PC
2. Restart program
3. unregister and reregister the phone
4. reinstall Update 3
5. reinstall VS2013
6. [Windows Phone 8 Application crash once its launched AgHost.exe' has exited with code -532265403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034074/windows-phone-8-application-crash-once-its-launched-aghost-exe-has-exited-with)
7. Install VS2015 with no luck.
8. reinstall VS2013 Update 4

Nothing worked. The error is also the same for emulator as well as different devices. I can however get the `release mode` installed. Break points can be used when using `release mode`, but I have to `Clean`, `Rebuild` and then `deploy` for every time I want to deploy the application. Further the deploy time has gone up exponentially. Before upgrading I used a maximum of 10 seconds. Now it is above a minute in wait time. :/

Anyone has a solution for  this ?

**Extra**

If I run the solution before upgrade on device or Emulator It spins up with debugger. If then go to the updated WP81, I get a popup with info `Something is taking longer then normal` and then it crashes with `..Ensure unlocked screen..` :/

Could it be an issue with the differen SDKS?
[image]
During a repair of all the SDKs, I found an issue with the event log, which I cleared based on [The Event Log File is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300216/the-event-log-file-is-full)

Still no success.

**Extra**

I cannot spin up the emulator from VS2013, when using the WP8.1 solution, but the wp8.0 solution in the same VS works :S

I found an error in a log file, from:

[image]

The errors are:

> [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:11:44]: Applying execute package: silverlight5_DRT, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\DEB5078B60B74431E2830831EB48DF129CB32932\packages\Silverlight\5.0_DRT\Silverlight_Developer.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\DEB5078B60B74431E2830831EB48DF129CB32932\packages\Silverlight\5.0_DRT\Silverlight_Developer.exe" /q /ignorewarnings'
>   [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:11:45]: Error 0x800705de: Process returned error: 0x5de
>   [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:11:45]: Error 0x800705de: Failed to execute EXE package.
>   [0550:0E74][2015-07-23T09:11:45]: Error 0x800705de: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
>   [0550:0E74][2015-07-23T09:11:45]: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: silverlight5_DRT MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0

AND

> [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:16:16]: Applying execute package:
>   {312d9252-c71c-4c84-b171-f4ad46e22098}, action: Repair, path:
>   C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{312d9252-c71c-4c84-b171-f4ad46e22098}\VS2012.4.exe, arguments:
>   '"C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{312d9252-c71c-4c84-b171-f4ad46e22098}\VS2012.4.exe" -repair
>   -quiet -burn.related.patch' [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:16:23]: Error 0x80048bc7: Process returned error: 0x80048bc7
>   [0F08:14A8][2015-07-23T09:16:23]: Error 0x80048bc7: Failed to execute
>   EXE package. [0550:0E74][2015-07-23T09:16:23]: Error 0x80048bc7:
>   Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

Anybody knows what to do with this? The error is coming when I repair `Windows Phone SDK 8.0`

Comment: Why not install update 4 for VS2013?

Comment: @OmegaMan sorry not mentioned above But I have done that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no Idea of what is the issue, but creating a new solution and importing the existing projects into a new solution has solved all the issues regarding emulator and debugger an AgHost.

Seems like the upgrade function integrated in the solution did not work properly.

Answer (score 6):

There was a post-VS2013 update for the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, some odds that you don't have it installed since you did not need it before.  The download location [is here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719).

Getting error messages like "port is in use" when there's no obvious reason why it should be in use and seeing excessive download times is also a very strong selector for your installed anti-malware product getting in the way.  No specific advice on how to configure it when we don't know what it might be.  You definitely first want to try to temporarily disable it so you can identify it as the source of the problem.

Comment: I only use the Microsoft anti-malware, this is not pc I use for anything but work.

Further If I revert the solution everything works as before. I will try with the update you refer to.

Comment: Don't just blindly assume it can't be the problem because it is from Microsoft.  A good example [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099199/visual-studio-and-msse-antivirus-compile-time-bug).  Experiment.

Comment: Of course it could be a problem, My point was more that if I revert the solution to WP8, then everything works fine and speed is fine. Upgrade to Wp8.1(silverlight) the issue returns.

Comment: So I updated/repaired with the package you suggested, but the system is still as bad when using WP8.1

Comment: I have now tried many different things, like reinstalling VS. I cannot find any anti-malware product other than windows- defender. I have become a bit desperat, so you suggest me to uninstall windows Defender, as the solution?

Comment: I tried removing the windows defender as per this homepage http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-remove-windows-defender-on-windows-8-1-windows-8 This did not help, it is still not possible to deploy the application on emulator or device with debugger, and still very slow on wp8.1 solutions. It seems like the upgrade has destroyed the solution? Moving the projects over into another solution seems to work for some reason. :/ Wasted my time :(