# xaml parse error on interaction triggers wp8.1(silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I have a working solution for WP8.0. But I needed to upgrade to get access to WNS. I have succeeded in adding WNS to the upgrade solution in the main menu works. But after Upgrading to wp8.1(silverlight), I have had some weird errors, that only happens on runtime. As an example it happens in the following usercontrol:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
xmlns:View="clr-namespace:ShieldGenerator.View"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
x:Class="ShieldGenerator.View.MoveableShieldGear"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Canvas.Left="{Binding Gear.x}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Gear.y}" Canvas.ZIndex="{Binding Gear.z}" >

<Path Data="{Binding Gear.Path}" Fill="{Binding Gear.Color}" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="{Binding Gear.Height}" Width="{Binding Gear.Width}" Opacity="{Binding Gear.Opacity}">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Gear.Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Gear.Scale}" CenterX="{Binding Gear.CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding Gear.CenterY}"/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Gear.Rotate}" CenterX="{Binding Gear.CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding Gear.CenterY}" />
            <SkewTransform AngleX="{Binding Gear.SkewX}" AngleY="{Binding Gear.SkewY}" CenterX="{Binding Gear.CenterX}" CenterY="{Binding Gear.CenterY}" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationStarted">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDownGearCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="ManipulationDelta">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseGearMoveCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="ManipulationCompleted">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseUpGearCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>

        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="DoubleTap">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DoubleTapCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</Path>

</UserControl>
```

Where the events are binded to my VM, the commands in the VM are defined as `RelayCommand`. As stated this was a working solution with no errors. I updated and still no errors when compiling. 
I have no code behind the view, but the error occurs in the line below marked with ERROR (in the *.g.cs file)

```
namespace ShieldGenerator.View {


public partial class MoveableShieldGear : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl {

    private bool _contentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// InitializeComponent
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/ShieldGenerator;component/View/MoveableShieldGear.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)); //ERROR
    }
}
}
```

The error refers to the line in `<i:Interaction.Triggers>` in the above xaml code.

I have tried uninstalling and installing several packages with no success.
I have tried to search around, and found ideas for including `Mode=Oneway`, and some stating error in the xaml parser. I am at a complete loss.

Hope somebody can help!

**The error**[image]

This error is displayed everywhere I use `i:interaction`. I have looked for a way to find an wp8.1 version of `System.Windows.Interactivity` But have not been able to do so. I have therefore made sure that the MVVMLight tools are updated:

[image]

**Information based on the Comment**

Difference in new `app.config`

        
        
      
Is a new addition.

Difference in new `WMAppManifest.xml`
NotificationService="WNS" Because I have set it up and it works

NEW

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" /> 
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
</Capabilities>
```

OLD

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
 </Capabilities>
```

I have removed the capabilities I did not use anymore. And added in the new `Package.appxmanifest` for WP8.1

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
<Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
<Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
```

I have per the other question also problem with the AGHost.exe, but I have not tried to delete it as I thought the below was mandatory.

```
<Applications>
<Application Id="xd82c080dy903dy47f4yba02y5a36d745c72bx" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="StartUp/FirstPage.xaml">
  <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="XXXXX" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="XXXX" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646" ToastCapable="true">
    <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
    </m3:DefaultTile>
    <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />
  </m3:VisualElements>
</Application>


</Applications>
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
</Capabilities>
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
      <Path>AgHostSvcs.dll</Path>
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="AgHost.BackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Cannot find any other issue in this file.
`AssemblyInfo.cs` and `AppManifest.xml` are the same. Looking at the reference folder the references seems okay, and are updated for wp8.1 (those that could)

**Extra**

If I copy the xaml code (i.e path with interaction) into another page that worked. Then it fails with the same error, during the xaml parsing for the page that worked without the snippet.

**New Update**
It seems that upon my upgrade something got damaged in the solutions and the projects. The following I has found, is that I can get the code up and working in a new project.
The code works if I run and deploy the project.

If I on the other hand use the same project, that worked when deployed, now navigate to it from another project `"/BC_Creator;component/MainPage.xaml"` Then the above error occurs again. My only idea now is to try and create completely new projects and copy-pasting the code into new files. Since importing them still does not seem to work.

WTF has happend :S

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: @ChrisW. added description of the error, Position 24 is the `.` in the line  `<i:Interaction.Triggers>`. I cannot extract the error message with the debugger because of another issue after upgrading. Referring to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432007/upgrading-wp8-to-wp8-1-silverlight-debugger-cannot-be-launched

Comment: Uh, ok... so by your line count and the mention of System.Windows.ni.dll in the exception, I'm going to say it's likely nothing to do with those triggers, or their interactions/namespaces etc. I would ask though, could you have possibly lost some project references in like your WMAppManifest.xaml that need to be manually added?

Comment: The odd thing is When I comment them put it Works. But still with the slow response s stated in the question I referred to. It is currently quite late here. I will try and compare tomorrow. Thank you so much for the proposal!

Comment: @ChrisW. I have now been able to find any errors, so I have added a lot of information :/ Because I am at quite a loss. Running the old code, i.e. before upgrading, everything works and I can run the solution with debugger attached. :/ :S But I need the new WNS Notification, which is why I upgraded. . .

Comment: @ChrisW. Now I do not have the issue anymore with launch of debugger or emulator. The VS2013, seems to work correctly. But I still get the error the same place, after importing the projects into a new solution.
My only idea is to create a new project and import the views and viewmodels to see if that was the only error. Since a simple test in a new solution with the above code worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still open for answers.

But my current result is that the it is in fact the MVVMLight package that is the issue.

After upgrading the solutions, uninstalling and reinstalling using the packmanager console, I had removed all errors. But the solution was not working. This has ended with me having to create a new solution and importing the old projects. Some of the issues however persisted, resulting in a copy-paster into new files, created with the same names. And suddenly it worked, so odd :/

The old solution is still not working, and even testing to import the old files (not project JUST code files) did not work, only recreating and copying worked.

It is really odd, so still open for solutions, because this will take a looong time!